# ExpressJS call another route in different route

Tags: node.js, express

I have this file called server.js

```
import subRouter from "./routes/sub";
import prdRouter from "./routes/prd";

const app = express();
app.use("/sub", subRouter);
app.user("/prd", prdRouter);

app.listen(3000);
```

Then I put different routes in different folders. Supposedly I want to use a route from file A in a route in file B as following:

sub.js:

```
const subRouter = Router();

subRouter.get("/some-endpoint", async (req, res) => {
  //do something
  res.send();
});

module.exports = subRouter;
```

prd.js:

```
const prdRouter = Router();

prdRouter.post("/some-prd-endpoint", async (req, res) => {
   //call (/some-endpoint) in subRouter and receive its response 
}

module.exports = prdRouter;
```

In prdRouter, how can I call /some-endpoint in subRouter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do if create a function and just call it in the other file.

`sub.js`:

```
const subRouter = Router();

function doSomething() {
  //...stuff
  return 'hello';
}

subRouter.get("/some-endpoint", async (req, res) => {
  const hello = doSomething();
  res.send(hello);
});

module.exports = {
  subRouter,
  doSomething
};
```

`prd.js`:

```
const sub = require('./sub');
const prdRouter = Router();

prdRouter.post("/some-prd-endpoint", async (req, res) => {
   const hello = sub.doSomething();
});

module.exports = prdRouter;
```

If you specifically want to actually call the endpoint then a regular http request is required. Install https://github.com/axios/axios or something similar.

`sub.js`:

```
const subRouter = Router();

subRouter.get("/some-endpoint", async (req, res) => {
  res.send();
});

module.exports = subRouter;
```

`prd.js`:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const prdRouter = Router();

prdRouter.post("/some-prd-endpoint", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:xxxx/some-endpoint'); // <--- replace here!
    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});

module.exports = prdRouter;
```

Replace `xxxx` with whatever your express server is using as it's port number.

Comment: I like the first approach, much cleaner.